# What is the Snap packaging format?

Tags: packaging, deb, snap

I have a very little knowledge about the 'Snap packaging format'. What I know is that 'Snap' is an alternative packaging format like .deb.

What I don't know is

- Why did Canonical chose it?
- What are the main advantages of 'Snap' over .deb?
- Will .deb be abandoned, or is it already abandoned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is snapcraft?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/686167/what-is-snapcraft)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The questions are related but  the suggested dupe asks about `snapcraft` - the set of tools for devs to create snap packages , which is just slightly different from what is being asked here

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Why did Canonical chose snaps?

To quote the [Ubuntu website](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/):

> We originally created the snappy technology and application
>   confinement system to ensure a carrier-grade update experience for
>   Ubuntu mobile users and set a new standard for application security in
>   the mobile era.

Essential idea was to fix issues that are present in both `.deb` packages and provide new method for updating the packages (the so called transactional updates , very similar to how android apps are updated). As [Mark Shuttleworth](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/) explains:

> Whenever we make a fix to packages in Ubuntu, we’ll publish the same
>   fix to Ubuntu Core, and systems can get that fix transactionally. In
>   fact, updates to Ubuntu Core are even smaller than package updates
>   because we only need to send the precise difference between the old
>   and new versions, not the whole package.

#### What are the main advantages of .snap packages over .deb packages?

The biggest advantage is the improved security. PPAs and `.deb` packages are typically installed with root privillege , which opens up a venue for security risks.

Snappy apps are isolated, meaning that if some app breaks, it won't break your systems. To quote Mark Shuttleworth:

> Snappy packages are automatically confined to ensure that a bug in one
>   app doesn’t put your data elsewhere at risk

#### Will .deb be abandoned?

As of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , both methods are available to the users.

To quote [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-lts-snap-packages):

> Canonical also say that “…the tens of thousands of applications and
>   packages in .deb format will continue to be supported in 16.04 and
>   beyond, and deb archives in particular will continue to be available
>   for all to use and distribute software.”

Comment: [Snappy apps on desktop Ubuntu aren't meaningfully isolated](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/42320.html) in Xenial.

Comment: @poolie yes, I'm aware of the xteddy.  The app is written in C and uses all the native tools of the X server.   It is in no way different  ( from what I see ) of other apps that allow control over Xserver behavior such as `xdotool` or `wmctrl`.  The issue isn't really with `snap` package, but with the X server - that's the main critique of it. Once Ubuntu moves away form X , it's will definitely bring around better security.

Comment: What does being written in C have to do with it? Is Snappy going to deprecate C?

Comment: IMO saying "Snappy apps are isolated" is not the whole truth, when they're not actually isolated on the current Ubuntu release, in the configuration used by 99% of users.  Snappy apps are less likely to accidentally conflict, yes.  Snappy apps are a foundation for security in a future release, probably.

Answer (score 12):

As an overview, as far as I understand snaps:

- Snaps are more secure. Running in own "containers".
- It's much more easy to handle with snaps than with deb packages.
- In the future, snaps will be the package format for mobile devices, internet of things and desktop.
- is or will be .deb abandoned? Canonical said, there will be support deb packages also in the future.

But there is a tool called `snapcraft`. With this tool its very easy to convert deb packages into snap packages.

Follow this link for more information. Maybe it helps you.
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/13/snaps-for-classic-ubuntu