# How to remove Skype?

Tags: uninstall, skype

Can anyone please tell me how to completely remove Skype from Ubuntu 18.04?

There's lots of advice on how to install Skype, but none on how to uninstall it. Skype came with the upgrade I think.

How can I remove Skype?

Comment: @Kulfy - you should post these as an answer in combo with a link to a snap description like https://askubuntu.com/questions/761245/what-is-the-snap-packaging-format, they are correct

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Click the "Ubuntu" button, type "Terminal" (without the quotations) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Type `sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux` (earlier package name was `skype`) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Enter your Ubuntu password to confirm that you wish to completely remove Skype and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Click the "Ubuntu" button, type "Home" (without the quotations) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open your home folder.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to display hidden folders. Locate and delete the ".skype" folder.
   Copied and pasted...

Comment: Not working: "package skype not found". Working answer is the one from Billal Begueradj.

Comment: Which is 'Ubuntu' button?

Comment: @Gathide The windows button :) .

Answer (score 80):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux
```

Comment: Good stuff. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

**GUI method** : Right click on Skype in app drawer and click Show details. You'll be redirected to Ubuntu Software Center. From there you can on uninstall. This would I call the easiest method.

**CLI method**: Open terminal and run `sudo snap remove skype` and if this doesn't work try `sudo apt-get --purge remove skype`

Read more:

- [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy) [answer to](https://askubuntu.com/a/761290/816190) [What is the Snap packaging format?](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy)

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal and run

```
sudo snap remove skype
```

it's worked for me.
if you find any problem then you can try another command

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skype/skypeforlinux
```

Here the answer already written. Further if you face any technical difficulties you can rewrite again.

Comment: thanks only this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

After removing Skype, you are to remove the remaining directories.

1. From your home directory write in the terminal command `find . -name Skype`
2. You will get the answer `./.config/Skype`
3. Go to the config directory `cd .config` and then type `ls`
4. You will see two directories named skype: Skype and skypeforlinux
5. `rm -r Skype skypeforlinux`
   And it's done.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed it through `snap`, then to uninstall it use:

```
sudo snap remove --purge skype
```

Answer (score 0):

here the way to remove Skype from Ubuntu recommended by the engineers of Microsoft :

source : [https://answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/how-to-uninstall-skypeforlinux-from-deb-file/3be0534c-ad1f-4dfe-bef9-6a2ee95a5ed5)

> 1. Go to "Applications."
> 2. Select a category and the program you wish to uninstall. Select "Uninstall" from the options listed with the program. Do not actually click the program itself. You want to view the other options listed with the program. If no uninstaller is available, continue to Step 3.
> 3. Go to "Applications -- Add/Remove" to open the Add/Remove programs window.
> 4. Type in the type of program you want to uninstall in the "Search" box. For instance, if you want to uninstall a browser, type "Internet" or "Browser". You can also use the categories to the left of the screen.
> 5. Uncheck the program you wish to uninstall and click "Apply." You may need to restart your computer.