# Two GNOMEs in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I found in the installed software tab of "Ubuntu Software" app that there are two GNOME runtime versions, 3.26 and 3.28. So, should I remove the lower version? Is it OK to remove GNOME 3.28 runtime?

Comment: Is that really "GENOME"? Do you mean "GNOME"?

Comment: Just as a general caution, please be careful when removing packages that come pre-installed. I prefer to open a terminal, and to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` and then to run `apt purge -s package_name` (where you'll enter the appropriate name instead of "package_name"). This last command is a simulation and doesn't require `sudo`. It will tell you what else the system plans to delete along with the package you propose to delete. Look at that output very carefully!

Answer (score 1):

These Gnome Runtimes you see are installed Snap packages of Gnome runtime files. If needed, you can [read here what Snap is about](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761245/what-is-the-snap-packaging-format).

Is it OK to remove the oldest one? Fact is, you won't be breaking your system at all. Only, you may then also cause the removal of one or more Snap applications that are using these runtimes. Anyway, even that does not really harm. If at some time you find yourself missing some application, just install it again. That will also automatically bring the needed runtime in (again).